# Somar valores de uma coluna de 12 em 12 linhas

Tags: r

Estou usando o RStudio e preciso somar os totais dos períodos que vão de outubro a setembro do ano seguinte.
Eu tentei usar intervalos com o summarise, mas são muitos dados para escrever intervalo por intervalo.

```
summarise (Dados[1:12,], sum(Total))
```

Não consegui descobrir algum tipo de loop que repetisse essa operação em intervalos de 12 em 12 até o fim da coluna.
Talvez exista alguma forma de referenciar através das datas?

Aqui segue um dataframe simplificado do que eu tenho (são mais colunas com todos os dias do 1 ao 31 e muito mais linhas):

```
Data      |   Total|NumDias|Dia1|Dia2|Dia30|Dia31|Meses|Ano
-----------------------------------------------------------
1998-10-01     200    16      0    0    12    0    10    1998
1998-11-01     170    10      0    0    25    0    11    1998
1998-12-01     235    12      0    0    5     0    12    1998
1999-01-01     120     6      0    0    0     0     1    1999 
1999-02-01     212    15      0    0    30    10    2    1999
1999-03-01     100    10      0    5    15     0    3    1999
1999-04-01      50     3      0    0     0     0    4    1999
1999-05-01      98     5      0    0     0     5    5    1999
1999-06-01     197     6      0    0    15    20    6    1999
1999-07-01      86     5     10    0    15     0    7    1999
1999-08-01     230     6      0   10    15    58    8    1999
1999-09-01     127    10     20   20    15     0    9    1999
1999-10-01     147     6      0    0    25     0   10    1999
1999-11-01      57    10      0    0     0     0   11    1999
1999-12-01      98     5      0    0     0     0   12    1999
```

As colunas Meses e Ano eu criei para calcular a média e o total anual. Mas referenciar outubro do ano anterior até setembro do ano seguinte, não estou conseguindo...

```
Dados <- mutate(Dados, Meses = month(Dados$Data))
Dados <- mutate(Dados, Ano = year(Dados$Data))
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema pode ser resolvido com um truque `cumsum` de valores lógicos, se o mês da coluna `Data` é igual a `"out"`. Depois calculam-se as somas agregadas dos totais mensais.

Primeiro simulo dados, já que não os há na pergunta.

```r
set.seed(2022)
start <- Sys.Date() - 10*12*30
Data <- seq.Date(start, Sys.Date(), by = "month")
`Total Mensal` <- sample.int(100, length(Data), TRUE)
Dados <- data.frame(Data, `Total Mensal`, check.names = FALSE)

mês <- format(Dados$Data, "%b")
Período <- cumsum(mês == "out")
aggregate(`Total Mensal` ~ Período, Dados, sum)
#>    Período Total Mensal
#> 1        0          229
#> 2        1          692
#> 3        2          610
#> 4        3          577
#> 5        4          583
#> 6        5          702
#> 7        6          634
#> 8        7          620
#> 9        8          547
#> 10       9          779
#> 11      10          223
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

## Edição

Depois dos comentários abaixo e da edição da pergunta com dados, aqui vai uma solução.

Primeiro, ler os dados.

```r
x <- 'Data         Total NumDias Dia1 Dia2 Dia30 Dia31 Meses Ano
1998-10-01     200    16      0    0    12    0    10    1998
1998-11-01     170    10      0    0    25    0    11    1998
1998-12-01     235    12      0    0    5     0    12    1998
1999-01-01     120     6      0    0    0     0     1    1999 
1999-02-01     212    15      0    0    30    10    2    1999
1999-03-01     100    10      0    5    15     0    3    1999
1999-04-01      50     3      0    0     0     0    4    1999
1999-05-01      98     5      0    0     0     5    5    1999
1999-06-01     197     6      0    0    15    20    6    1999
1999-07-01      86     5     10    0    15     0    7    1999
1999-08-01     230     6      0   10    15    58    8    1999
1999-09-01     127    10     20   20    15     0    9    1999
1999-10-01     147     6      0    0    25     0   10    1999
1999-11-01      57    10      0    0     0     0   11    1999
1999-12-01      98     5      0    0     0     0   12    1999'

Dados <- read.table(
  textConnection(x), 
  header = TRUE,
  colClasses = c("Date", rep("integer", 8))
)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Depois usar a mesma forma de criar uma variável que divida os dados por períodos de 12 meses a começar em Outubro, mas desta vez com `grepl`.

```r
mês <- format(Dados$Data, "%Y %b")
Período <- cumsum(grepl("out", mês, ignore.case = TRUE))
Dados_agg <- aggregate(Total ~ Período, Dados, sum)
Dados_agg
#>   Período Total
#> 1       1  1825
#> 2       2   302
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Como os períodos estão com os valores numéricos produzidos por `cumsum`, é melhor torná-los legíveis.

```r
mês <- tapply(mês, Período, `[`, 1)
match(names(mês), Dados_agg$Período)
#> [1] 1 2
Dados_agg$Período[match(names(mês), Dados_agg$Período)] <- mês

Dados_agg
#>    Período Total
#> 1 1998 out  1825
#> 2 1999 out   302
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

## Solução `tidyverse`

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(zoo)
})

Dados %>%
  mutate(grp = cumsum(grepl("-10-", Data))) %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  summarise(
    Data = as.yearmon(first(Data)),
    Total = sum(Total),
    .groups = "drop"
  ) %>%
  select(-grp)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   Data      Total
#>   <yearmon> <int>
#> 1 out 1998   1825
#> 2 out 1999    302
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Obrigada, @Rui_Barradas! Mas não funcionou. A linha mês <- format(Dados$Data, "%b") retorna um erro: invalid 'trim' argument

Comment: @Francisca Tente `class(Dados$Data)`, se não for `"Date"` faça `Dados$Data<-as.Date(Dados$Data)` primeiro.

Comment: @Rui_Barradas, não funcionou. Retorna o total de todos os valores da coluna Total. Mas você ajudou muito. A partir dos códigos que sugeriu, pude direcionar melhor minha pesquisa e consegui!! Vou por em outro comentário a solução. Obrigadão!!

Comment: @Francisca Com dados tornou-se mais fácil, veja se a edição resolve o problema.

Comment: Consegui de modo mais simples. Segue no outro comentário.

Comment: #cria coluna referencia para o periodo
```Dados <- mutate(Dados, Ref= cumsum(Meses == 10))```
#cria df com os totais dos periodos
```Dados2 <- aggregate(Total ~ Ref, Dados, sum)```
#insere a coluna do ano referencia do periodo 
```Dados2$Ano <- 1968:2019```

Comment: @Rui_Barradas consegui com o código acima. Os resultados ficam em outro dataframe, Dados2. Existe alguma forma desses resultados ficarem numa nova coluna no df Dados? Os valores resultantes das somas se repetiriam nas linhas com mesmo periodo.

Comment: @Francisca `Dados2` é um df com *menos* linhas, uma vez que cada linha é o agragado de 12. A nova coluna não pode estar em `Dados` a não ser que queira repetir os totais de 12 meses em cada linha. Isso pode ser feito: `Dados$Total12 <- ave(Dados$Total, Período, FUN = sum)`.